# data.table rejects to create new column when used in a chain

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to `data.table` packcage and become confused about its chaining behavior. Suppose we have the following code:

```
aa <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b = c("a","b","b"))
aa[order(a,b)][,c:=cumsum(a), by=.(b)]
> aa
   a b
1: 1 a
2: 2 b
3: 3 b
```

Column `c` is not created.

But if we write the code seperately without chaining, `c` can be genereted:

```
aa <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b = c("a","b","b"))
aa[order(a,b)]
   a b
1: 1 a
2: 2 b
3: 3 b
aa[,c:=cumsum(a), by=.(b)]
> aa
   a b c
1: 1 a 1
2: 2 b 2
3: 3 b 5
```

So why does this happen? How can I write the chain code correctly using `data.table`?

Thank you a lot!

**Below is new**

I noticed that, if we assign it to a new dataframe, it worked again:

```
aa <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b = c("a","b","b"))
bb <- aa[order(a,b)][,c:=cumsum(a), by=.(b)]
> bb
   a b c
1: 1 a 1
2: 2 b 2
3: 3 b 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to the order. You can try

```
aa[,c:=cumsum(a), by=.(b)][order(a,b)]
```

In this line `aa[order(a,b)][,c:=cumsum(a), by=.(b)]`, it can be viewed as `tmp <- aa[order(a,b)], tmp[,c:=cumsum(a), by=.(b)]`. Column `c` is indeedly created but not in original `aa` if you run `aa[order(a,b)][,c:=cumsum(a), by=.(b)][]` to check.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. So is the safest way to not use chain to create new columns?

Comment: Yes, I think so.